# Move div element to the middle of the screen in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you animate a div element to the middle of the screen from the left side

I get this invalid obect or prperty 
i can't seem to reference the jQuery(document) object through jQuery anymore

```
form.each(function () {
    jQuery(this).animate({ marginLeft: jQuery(document).width / 2 }, 750); <-- this line here gives me errors
    jQuery('input[name^=Next]').click(function () {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the div's `marginLeft` property. Just check out the examples. Here is a quick mock-up:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({
    marginLeft: '+=' + $(document).width() / 2
}, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/W6v2B/

Comment: I've edited my question i've got a new problem. I'm making a plugin for the first time and it's not working well. I can't reference the document or even use the jQuery( to reference the document ) what's my problem

Comment: I figured it out i made a typo sorry. width() duh

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Here is a simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='walker'>Hello World</div>
<input type='button' id='move' value='move'>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#move').live('click', function(event) {        
       $("#walker").animate({marginLeft: $(window).width()/2,}, 1500 );
   });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kfwYh/)

- [Fun With jQuery’s Animate() Function](http://www.viget.com/inspire/fun-with-jquerys-animation-function/)